# fetch data from mysql in php does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing sth like this:

```
$q3 = $conn3->prepare("SELECT...");
    $q3->bindParam(':param1', $param1);
    $q3->execute();

$check3 = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($check3)){

$arr = array();
while($row = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
       $arr[] = $row;
    }
```

}

but I don't see the data in arr[] later on. What exactly am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to fetch the data from mysql to an array in php?

Comment: `fetchAll()` Because you already feteched the data?!

Comment: Can you give me more detailed answer? I'm sorry if that's dumb question, I'm just starting learing php...

Comment: Do `print_r($check3);` right after `fetchAll()` And you will know what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)** returns the next row in the set.  **[fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)** will fetch all the (remaining) rows and move the pointer to the last row, therefore `fetch()` after `fetchAll()` will not return anything because there will not be a next row in the set.

You need one or the other.  To take advantage of fetchAll you could do:

```
$check3 = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($check3 as $row) {

}
```

or just use fetch without fetchAll:

```
while ($row = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

}
```

Your code, as is, makes the `fetch()` useless.  You could just do:

```
$arr = $q3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $q3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
       $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I verify if the query returned at least one row? previously I did if (!empty($check3)){ but now I don't see a place for it..

Comment: There's a place for it before the foreach.  Using `$q3->rowCount()` will work on MySQL. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php